# Working with ASPX pages

Tags: windows, asp.net, web-hosting, website

If I connect via FTP and make edits to a .aspx file and upload it do I need to have the webhost do any type of complile or something?

Comment: Are you doing any kind of caching of the .aspx files on the web server?  If so, those would have to be flushed but that would be a rare case.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the file worked before (IIS is set up to allow asp.net sites here), it will be re-compiled automatically.

Answer (score 2):

No. You don't need to do anything.